# Error when binding Ext.grid.Panel to Ext.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am new to extJS. I want to bind a `Ext.grid.Panel` to `Ext.Panel` (yes, I really want that!). This is what I've tried -

```
Var Panel = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Test',
    id: 'Panel',
    items: [Grid]
});

Var Grid =
{
xtype: 'grid',
columns: [
    { header: 'Resort', dataIndex: 'resort' },
    { header: 'Arrival', dataIndex: 'arrival' },
    { header: 'Accompanying Guest(s)', dataIndex: 'guest', flex: 1 }
]
};
```

Now I want to open `Panel` in a `Ext.Window`

```
var win2 = new Ext.Window({
                    layout: 'fit',
                    width: 900,
                    height: 600,
                    closeAction: 'hide',
                    plain: true,
                    items: [Panel]                        
                });
                b.getEl().on('click', function () {
                    win2.show();
                });
```

This ends in an error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined`

But when I change the `Panel` as below, its working fine-

```
var Panel = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Test',
    id: 'Panel',
    items:
        [
            {
                xtype: 'grid',
                columns: [
                        { header: 'Resort', dataIndex: 'resort' },
                        { header: 'Arrival', dataIndex: 'arrival' },
                        { header: 'Accompanying Guest(s)', dataIndex: 'guest', flex: 1 }
                ]
            }
        ]
});
```

What went wrong in my previous code?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't work. You're essentially doing this:

```
var y = x + 1;
console.log(y); // Why isn't y 2?
var x = 1;
```

Comment: ok I agree that, but what if the `Grid` is in another `.js file`?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, you can't run code out of order.

Comment: ok, I've 1 more questions 1. What the difference between `var Grid =
{
    xtype: 'grid',....` and `var Grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {...`

Comment: 2. 've a `data.store` -`Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'StoreId',
    fields: ['resort', 'arrival', 'guest'],
    data: { 'items': [
        { 'resort': '00CPT', "arrival": "16 Jun 2013", "guest": "Judy Roehsner" },
        { 'resort': '', "arrival": "", "guest": "Robert Roehsner" }
    ]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});`

Comment: when I assigned this store to `Var Grid =
    {
    xtype: 'grid',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('StoreId'),
    columns: [
        { header: 'Resort', dataIndex: 'resort' },
        { header: 'Arrival', dataIndex: 'arrival' },
        { header: 'Accompanying Guest(s)', dataIndex: 'guest', flex: 1 }
    ]
    };` its end up in error. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to define your grid before you use it in items as below :

```
var Grid = {
    xtype: 'grid',
    columns: [{
        header: 'Resort',
        dataIndex: 'resort'
    }, {
        header: 'Arrival',
        dataIndex: 'arrival'
    }, {
        header: 'Accompanying Guest(s)',
        dataIndex: 'guest',
        flex: 1
    }]
};

var Panel = new Ext.Panel({
   // title: 'Test',
    id: 'Panel',
    items: [Grid]
});
```

Or else one more option is (When you have grid in different js file you can go with listeners as  done below ) :

```
        var Panel = new Ext.Panel({
            // title: 'Test',
            id: 'Panel',
            items: [],
            listeners: {
                render: function(pnl) {
                    pnl.add(Grid);
                }

            }
        });

        var Grid = {
            xtype: 'grid',
            columns: [{
                header: 'Resort',
                dataIndex: 'resort'
            }, {
                header: 'Arrival',
                dataIndex: 'arrival'
            }, {
                header: 'Accompanying Guest(s)',
                dataIndex: 'guest',
                flex: 1
            }]
        };

        var win2 = new Ext.Window({
            layout: 'fit',
            width: 500,
            height: 400,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            plain: true,
            items: [Panel]
        });
        b.getEl().on('click', function() {
            win2.show();
```

Below is the fiddle to represnt same

[Demo](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1qe)